# Running code (loop) server side and retrieving output later on

Tags: multithreading, data-processing

I am trying to do a simple program that keeps track of some internet data. I can get the data from a public JSON object, so that's not really the problem. I would like to automize the process as much as possible. I need to use HTML code and run it from a browser in order to keep it running. If I close the browser, the thread dies. Keeping threads alive until I kill them is pretty much the objective.

I know how to use C#, Python, Java, and C/C++. However I have no experience with server programming. The question basically is, how can I keep a program running on the server to later on be able to retrieve the output?

Note: I'm not sure of which tags to use.

Comment: I've tried looking for tutorials/documentation, but I can't seem to find what I need.

Comment: Even though I think the question isn't clear enough, if you need a thread to do a job to be done on a server (i.e.: thinking in Java) you can have an instance of Runnable/Thread types, that instance could store the processing results somewhere (file, db, shared memory) and then you could serve/provide that data with an instance of Servlet. Then on your Html file you could have a <script/> (Javascript) with an instance of XMLHttpRequest that consumes the service contents (provided by Servlet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are new you have a bit of learning to do. I would highly reccomend you play with django and understand how to make a simple webpage with it. This (or ruby on rails) is how professionals serve webpages.

Once you understand how to install / use the framework you can look at this link for background tasks: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-background-task

In Ruby on Rails these are called rake tasks. After the task is done you usually retrieve the output using the database ( or write results to a file on disk).

If you don't know how to setup or run a server I would look at heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/. They have a free tier of servers which works easily with git and is seriously zero hassle. That link has instructions for the multiple languages they support. Good luck!!